# JSON: how to parse the property names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have a lot of json data fetched from a SQL databases similar to this one below:

```
var data = [
        {"id": 0, "gender": "male", "name": "joan"},
        {"id": 1, "gender": "female", "name": "pep"},
        {"id": 2, "gender": "female", "name": "maria"},
        {"id": 3, "gender": "female", "name": "meli"},
        {"id": 4, "gender": "female", "name": "jaume"}
            ];
```

How can I get in Javascript (jQuery or underscore.js would be better)?

```
keys = ["id", "gender", "name"];
```

(sorry for duplicates, I couldn't find something exactly like this)

UPDATE: Yes this can be considered a duplicate if you take the first element of the **data** array, this is: **data[0]**

Then, the shortest given solution (using underscore.js) is

```
keys = _.keys(data[0]);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON btw, `data` is an array.

Comment: Since the question is tagged [tag:Underscore.js], use [`_.keys()`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys)!

Answer (score 2):

using jquery.each you can get the key of json objects

```
     var keys = [];

    $.each(data[0], function(key, value){
         console.log(key); // id, gender, name
         console.log(value); // 0, male, joan
         keys.push(key);
        });
```

console.log(keys); // ["id", "gender", "name"]

Answer (score 1):

If all objects have the same keys, [jquery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) might be useful:

```
keys = $.map(data[0], function(val, key) { return key })
```

For a pure javascript solution consider [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: thank, but I get keys empty